# How to go second activity from first activity on button click and Third activity from Second on button click in android

Tags: android, android-intent

Hi guys i am using 3 activities in my android app which are

1.main_activity

2.Secondactivity

3.Third Activity

I am facing problem when i try to open  the *Second activity* from main activity via a button click on main activity. The app crashes and dose not work

I also need to open my *Third Activity* via a Button click on *Second Activity* When it is opened

As i am new to android coding am not able to understand where i am doing wrong in my coding. I would like to seek info about and also need any one who can help me out with this

Thanks in advance

Below is the complete code and the Error am getting is this

```
07-27 12:13:51.887 23039-23039/com.example.mohammadzakriya.tech_bgkapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
     Process: com.example.mohammadzakriya.tech_bgkapp, PID: 23039
     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mohammadzakriya.tech_bgkapp/com.example.mohammadzakriya.tech_bgkapp.Secondactivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
      Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
         at com.example.mohammadzakriya.tech_bgkapp.Secondactivity.OnclickButtonListener(Secondactivity.java:24)
         at com.example.mohammadzakriya.tech_bgkapp.Secondactivity.onCreate(Secondactivity.java:19)
         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) "**
                                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
```

Here is Android main Activity.java file :

```
package com.example.mohammadzakriya.tech_bgkapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    public static Button button_smb;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        OnclickButtonListener();
    }

    public void OnclickButtonListener(){
        button_smb =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        button_smb.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.mohammadzakriya.tech_bgkapp.Secondactivity");
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
        );
    }
}
```

Here is Second Activity.java file :

```
package com.example.mohammadzakriya.tech_bgkapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Secondactivity extends Activity{

    public static Button button_smb1;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_secondactivity);
        OnclickButtonListener();
    }

    public void OnclickButtonListener(){
        button_smb1 =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        button_smb1.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        Intent myintent = new Intent("com.example.mohammadzakriya.tech_bgkapp.ThirdActivity");
                        startActivity(myintent);
                    }
                }
        );
    }
}
```

Main Activity xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.mohammadzakriya.tech_bgkapp.MainActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/frontpic">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Click to proceed"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic|normal"
        android:textSize="19dp"
        android:background="#d55b26f8"
        android:textColor="#e2e0e0" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="     WELCOME TO BAGALKOT APP"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:background="#fbe47d0e"
        android:textColor="#e2e0e0" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Second Activity xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.mohammadzakriya.tech_bgkapp.Secondactivity"
    android:background="#eb5d16ea">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ELECTRONICS"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic|normal"
        android:background="#eec16d0d"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textColor="#e2e0e0"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="              SELECT THE CATEGORY"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic|"
        android:background="#fbe47d0e"
        android:textColor="#e2e0e0"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Android manifest file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.mohammadzakriya.tech_bgkapp">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Secondactivity"
            android:label="Tech-Bgk App">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.mohammadzakriya.tech_bgkapp.Secondactivity" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".ThirdActivity"
                  android:label="Tech-Bgk App">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.mohammadzakriya.tech_bgkapp.ThirdActivity" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try with code like below

Button click on MainActivity to go to SecondActivity

```
   @Override
   public void onClick(View view) {
       Intent myintent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
       startActivity(myintent);
   }
```

And Button click on SecondActivity to go to ThirdActivity

```
   @Override
   public void onClick(View view) {
       Intent myintent = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, ThirdActivity.class);
       startActivity(myintent);
   }
```

**Edited**

Everything in your code is fine except initialization of `button_smb1` in Secondactivity.

Please do the change in Secondactivity as

`button_smb1 =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);`.

Now it will be working. No need to change anything other than.

Comment: Done the edits which u have mentioned above but couldn't solve the error .Do i need to make changes in the Android manifest file before applying the edits?

Comment: Please do this in second activity `button_smb1 =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);`. Now it will be working. No need to change anything other than.

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Secondactivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

In my experience, this is how you move from one `Activity` to another `Activity` through code.

And one more thing, that's a weird way to add an `onClickListener()`, if it's just a simple "First Activity to second Activity" you should just directly declare the Button and set the `onClickListener()`

```
Button button_smb =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
button_smb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Secondactivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        }
}
```

Comment: I think here `this` is referencing `OnClickListener` object, not referencing `Activity`. So I think it will give you an error or it will not give you the desire output.

Comment: Ohooo I almost always forget that, sorry, editting it

Comment: That's why always try to use a Context object, it will keep you safe.

Comment: Context object? What is that?

Comment: `Context context = MainActivity.this;` initialize it in `onCreate` method. It is safer.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks for the info, which one is better, always have MainActivity.this or declaring a Context object that way in terms of performance and memory usage?

Answer (score 0):

Replace below code in your mainActivity  file .

```
button_smb.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Secondactivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
        );
```

Comment: Here `this` will refer `OnClickListener` object. So it will not work I think.

Answer (score 0):

Try like,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Secondactivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

this should helps you

Answer (score 0):

Change below code
**Main activity to second activity**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Secondactivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

**Second activity to third activity**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ThirdActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the new, i prefer use this approch:

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompactActivity implents View.OnClickListener{

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ....
    button.setOnClickListener(this);
    ...
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

    Intent i;
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.button1:                     
            i = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("extra", 0); //if you want pass some info to other activity
            startActivity(i);
            break;
         default:
            break;
     }
}
```

In this way you can handle more onclick in one function, switching by component's id